# MULTI-TABBING ISSUE For one of the Java Web Application - Mixing the data from two different records

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, session, struts

**Problem:**
Whenever we save the data of two different records in two different tabs of the browser for the same session, data is getting mixed up for the respective saved records.

**Scenario:**
1) **Tab1:** Open the browser and login to the application and go the search screen. (In our case Guarantor search screen).

2) **Tab2:** Open another browser tab in the same browser, copy the URL of the previous step and paste it into the current tab, now search screen opened in both the tab.

3) Go back to Tab1 and search for one guarantor (for ex: Guarantor with some number like 34526) and open it once after getting the result in the search screen.

4) Then go to Tab2 and search for another Guarantor record and open the same.

5) Now Click on Edit button for editing the record opened in Tab2 and then go back to Tab1 without editing the data in Tab2.

6) Now Click on Edit button for editing the record opened in Tab1 and then make the modifications and do some action in this screen like 'SAVE' operation, at the same time Go to Tab2 and click on 'SAVE' operation on this screen also. Now Here we clicked the save button on Tab1 and in the mean time before Tab1 completes its save operation we did another action (i.e. SAVE) in Tab2 also.

7) Now data got mixed up for both the screens at this time (which is not a correct behavior). In this case data shouldn't be mixed up, it should be saved properly for the corresponding record.
Please note that in the above scenario opened screen will be same for both the tabs but with Different record. (For example: Opened the screen for 'Edit Guarantor' but with two different Guarantor records).

**Preferred Solution By Client:**

Application should allow to make the changes for the records opened in multiple tabs without breaking the application flow. The user logged into the application will be same in the case and application should allow multi-tabbing feature without mixing up of the data.

**Possible Root causes for the issue are:**

1) Browser version from IE 7 and above maintains single session throughout the browser, even if you open new window also it will be having the same session.
Since we are using IE8, it maintains single session even through different Tabs also. Which might be creating this problem.

We did some research on the above issue and also checked with some blogs but we are not able to trace the correct solution for our problem.

We checked few things to solve this issue like:

1) *SessionStorage* concept which is available from HTML5 and can support from IE8+ browsers but this solution won't support our requirement which we mentioned above. If anybody got the above results with the help of this please let us know.

2) We found another solution: URL re-writing - (appending the session details nd some unique details to distinguish the session and maintain some hidden fields to keep track of the session in each and every page) - But this is very complex and also we are not sure whether this solve the above said problem. Please let us know if any suggestions in this regard.

We also tried some examples with some JavaScript coding but didn't get required solution with them.

We are expecting some guidance or similar solution if somebody already implemented in their application.

Comment: You need to implement page-specific conversations, like Seam etc did/does. That's the nature of sessions.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the scope of your form bean to request? By default, struts's form bean is session scoped. So the bean that you are posting back to the server is shared between the tabs. If you set the scope to request, then you will have different form beans in different tabs. This will ensure that when the user hits save, data is not mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue with couple of struts applications which asks users to fill the data on multiple pages (users fills data on one page, clicks next ...reaches till last page and click on save and then the data is saved in the database). When user clicks on next to go to the next page, the current page (form) data is saved in the HttpSession (Struts automatically does that, if the bean scope is session). When the user opens the application in multiple tabs or browser windows (assuming user is using same browser (e.g. IE) for multiple windows) and acting on forms for different records, data gets saved/overwritten in the same session and gets corrupted. Your case is also similar.

As you rightly pointed out the jsessionID is little bit complex to implement because if you are rendering some links (links pointing to other part of the application from an xml file) on your web page, you need to embed the jsessionID in the URL otherwise server will assign a new jsessionID and will redirect the user to the login page (assuming your enterprise application asks the user to login first)( Dynamically generated link will have the jsessionID already embedded with them). Second problem with this approach is : if user right clicks on any link (assuming jsessionID is embedded in it) and select open in a new window/tab and then navigate to some other record to edit it, your data will get corrupted (Please note that when user selects open in new tab for a link, the URL for that link will already have the same jsessionID from the parent window/tab).

To solve the issue, you will have to make some design changes in your application. Below is the possible approach.

Rather than storing the data in HttpSession, you can store the data in a cache ( you can have your own logic to store data as key value pair, explained below ). I guess you will have to follow below steps:
    a) Change the bean scope to request from the session.
    b) Have a unique identifier for each window/tab. You can use windows.name property for the same. This property is supported by all the major browsers. You should send this tab/window name to the server each time you click on next/previous/save.
    c) At server side to store the data, below approach can be followed (May not be the best one, feel free to tune it. :-) )

```
    HashMap -> key will be the jessionID and value will be another HashMap.
          - HashMap(value of the first Map) -> key will be tab/windows name sent from the browser. Value will be another HashMap.
                   - HashMap (value of the second map) -> Key will be form name. Value will be the actual form. (this map will have only one entry, if you have only one form).

d) Once you approach on the last page, get all the forms from the Map for the desired tab/window and save in the database.
```

For point (c) mentioned above, you can use the database to store the intermediate data. Both the approaches have pros and cons.
    i) Storing/retrieving data in/from Map/Data Structure is faster compared to the database.
    ii) Storing data in data structure consumes space on the heap. However as of now you store data in the session so that should not be an issue.
    iii) Data gets lost in case of server crash, if stored in the DS. From the database data can be retrieved back.